# La consola muestra "Promise { <pending> } al momento de usar Async Await en Node.JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo el siguiente código en Node.JS:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
var respuesta;

var nombre = async function (username){
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`
    var respuesta = await fetch (url)
    var response = await respuesta.json();
    return response.login;        
}
console.log(nombre('zac3599'));
```

El problema que tengo es que al ejecutarlo me muestra `Promise { <pending> }`. ¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Gracias

Comment: La consola muestra pending cuando todavía no ha terminado la ejecución de la promise (no se ha resuelto). Cuando termine, si vuelves a imprimir tu promise verás que pone "resolved" (o "rejected" si es caso)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Observación

Lo que te esta sucediendo no esta relacionado al contenido de tu función como tal, sino a la naturaleza asíncrona de tu función y la forma en como la estas ejecutando, es importante saber que cuando tenemos una función async await lo que en realidad estamos creando es una promesa que es capaz de resolverse internamente, por ello dentro de tu `console.log(nombre('zac3599'));` lo que estas realmente haciendo es imprimiendo la promesa que retorna tu función, puedes lograr superar esta dificultad de presentas de varias formas, a continuación te mostrare tres que puedes usar dependiendo de tus necesidades:

### Resolviendo promesa con then

Puedes hacer uso de la función `then` para resolver tu promesa pasando un callback que reciba el resultado de tu función de la siguiente forma:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
var respuesta;

var nombre = async function (username){
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`
    var respuesta = await fetch (url)
    var response = await respuesta.json();
    return response.login;        
}

nombre('zac3599').then(val => console.log(val))
```

### Resolviendo promesa con closure

Puedes implementar un closure que se ejecute de forma asincrona y que te permita resolver tu promesa y recibir el valor de retorno de la siguiente forma:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
var respuesta;

var nombre = async function (username){
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`
    var respuesta = await fetch (url)
    var response = await respuesta.json();
    return response.login;        
}

(
    async () => {
        console.log(await nombre('zac3599'))
    }
)()
```

### Resolviendo promesa con otra función

Así también muy probablemente te habrás dado cuenta que podemos hacer lo mismo que hicimos con el closure pero con otra función desde la cual desees realizar el llamado de una forma similar a la siguiente:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
var respuesta;

var nombre = async function (username){
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`
    var respuesta = await fetch (url)
    var response = await respuesta.json();
    return response.login;        
}

const otrafuncion = async () => {
    console.log(await nombre('zac3599'))
}
```

### Material de apoyo

Puedes encontrar temas relacionados a async await y promesas en los siguientes enlaces:

- [Funciones asíncronas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)
- [Uso de await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/await)
- [Promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas)

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: muy bueno 

Comment: No siempre me funciona, por ejemplo `let text = await response.text()` me termina diciendo `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` pero `response.text()` es `Promise { <pending> }`.